# How do you make an entity visible in a place, but not actually there?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft, I have a world that I am making a mini game in, and I have an Iron Golem that's always teleporting to a horse. I want the player of the mini-game to be able to ride the horse and have the looks of the Iron Golem, but the Iron Golem won't allow the horse to get damaged or for the player to get on the horse.

The commands I have used are:

```
/summon minecraft:horse ~ ~1 ~ {Variant:0,CustomName:testhorse,CustomNameVisible:1,PersistenceRequired:0b,Glowing:1,CanPickUpLoot:0b,Health:600,Fire:0,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Base:0.1f},{Name:"horse.jumpStrength",Base:0f}],Tame:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:2147483647}]}
```

To spawn the horse.

```
/summon minecraft:villager_golem ~ ~1 ~ {NoAI:1b,PersistenceRequired:0b,LeftHanded:0,Invulnerable:1}
```

To spawn the Iron Golem.

```
/tp @e[type=Villager_Golem] @e[type=horse]
```

To teleport the golem to the horse

Comment: Maybe by letting a golem ride an invisible horse.

Comment: If I make it ride the horse then the player cannot ride the horse and the iron golem will be floating

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is impossible without mods, however what you can do is teleport the iron golem to the horse after the player gets on.

Comment: thanks that is a good idea i might make the horses texture the iron golems texture than you can ride it and it will look like a iron golem maby if that works if not i will do it the way you suggested and see how that goes

Comment: I recommend RS_Mind's approach. You can have the iron golem teleport slightly to the side of the horse until the player gets on, then to the horse's  exact location once they are in place. Your retexturing approach would make the horse (not the player) look like an iron golem, and I don't see how it could be done without mods or texture packs anyway.